# How to configure VSCode Intellisens to use headers with custom extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I work on a C project where there are two types of headers used, .h and .cfg. The recommended editor is Eclipse but I am trying to use VSCode instead. I ran into a problem, VSCode's Intellisense only sees .h files.

If I add add each folder containing the .cfg files by hand, the includes are seen by Intellisense. This is however quite annoying because there are hundreds of folders to be added.

I searched on stackoverflow and on the internet for a solution but I can't seem to find an answer.

Is there a way to VSCode's Intellisense to consider headers with extension .cfg(or any other custom extension)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe this could help: [Adding a file extension to a language - Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language)

Comment: @ErdalKüçük `files.associations` are used to determine the language ID of a loaded file in an editor

Comment: I tried to add *.cfg as a c file in files.associations for the Workspace however Intellisense doesn't recognize the a cfg file which is not part of the manually added locations in the includePath.

Comment: because `files.associations` is used by the editor not by the language server